# concurrent bookings

Tags: sql

I have a table on booking orders

Bookings (order_no, user_id, booking_time,complete_time)

I try to write a query to return the order_no from all rows where customers made concurrent bookings (customer made a new booking before they completed the previous booking).

Explanation:

Customer X booked #000 at 1:15, and completed it at 1:25.

Customer X booked #001 at 1:20, and completed it at 1:25.

Customer X booked #002 at 5:30, and completed it at 6:00.

Customer Y booked #020 at 1:20, and completed it at 2:10.

Customer Y booked #021 at 6:55, and completed it at 7:16.

Only Customer X had a concurrent booking. The correct query would return order_no #000 and #001.

Output should be

000

001

I have tried using subquery in the criteria, but I still don’t get the logic
I need help with this, Please someone help me

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both bookings on *separate* rows, then one method is window functions:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             lag(booking_time) over (partition by user_id order by booking_time) as prev_booking_time,
             lead(booking_time) over (partition by user_id order by booking_time) as next_booking_time,
             lag(coalesce(complete_time, cancel_time) over (partition by user_id order by booking_time) as prev_end_time
      from bookings b
     ) b
where (next_booking_time >= booking_time and
       next_booking_time < coalesce(complete_time, cancel_time) 
      ) or
      (booking_time > prev_booking_time and
       booking_time < prev_end_time
      );
```

If you want the overlaps on one row, then you can do:

```
select b1.*, b2.*
from bookings b1 join
     bookings b2
     on b2.user_id = b1.user_id and
        b2.booking_time >= b1.booking_time and
        (b2.booking_time <= b1.complete_time) or
         b2.booking_time <= b1.cancel_time
        );
```

Note that for multiple overlaps on the same booking, this produces a row for each pair.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the overlapping date range problem.  You may solve this via a self join:

```sql
SELECT b1.*
FROM Bookings b1
INNER JOIN Bookings b2
    ON b1.user_id = b2.user_id AND
       b1.order_no <> b2.order_no
WHERE
    b2.booking_time  < b1.complete_time AND
    b2.complete_time > b1.booking_time;
```